Running an Azure Function locally results in a worker error
I created a local Azure function project on Windows using the following CLI commands from the Azure documentation:
func init --python
 
func new --name HttpExample --template "HTTP trigger" --authlevel "anonymous"


Running these commands results in the following Azure function being created:
import azure.functions as func
import datetime
import json
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.route(route="HttpExample", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.anonymous)
def HttpExample(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )

The requirements.txt created by the Azure Function Core Tools includes only the azure-functions library.
After starting the function with the func start command, the worker exits with the following error:
Found Python version 3.12.0 (py).

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.6610 Commit hash: N/A +0d55b5d7efe83d85d2b5c6e0b0a9c1b213e96256 (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.1036.1.23224

[2024-12-20T13:20:17.095Z]  ERROR: unhandled error in functions worker: '_SixMetaPathImporter' object has no attribute '_path'
[2024-12-20T13:20:17.127Z] Language Worker Process exited. Pid=13732.
[2024-12-20T13:20:17.128Z] py exited with code 1 (0x1). AttributeError: '_SixMetaPathImporter' object has no attribute '_path',AttributeError: '_SixMetaPathImporter' object has no attribute '_path',AttributeError: '_SixMetaPathImporter' object has no attribute '_path'.
[2024-12-20T13:21:15.126Z] Starting worker process failed
[2024-12-20T13:21:15.129Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Grpc: The operation has timed out.
[2024-12-20T13:21:15.133Z] Failed to start language worker process for runtime: python. workerId:ed1a4b3d-07d0-41f7-9116-2f60397a6748

How can I fix this?
What I tried:

I checked that the core Azure Functions Core Tools were working properly
I updated pip and recreated the python venv
I reinstalled Azure Function Core Tools
I checked that npm and node.js were properly installed and functioning
I re-did all steps from the documentation in a different directory to make sure I didn't miss anything


Is it Python V2 function? Provide your requirements.txt and function code.

Thank you for the suggestion. I have added the function code and requirements to the question.

The function created by core tools was a V2 function.

You are getting error because of the invalid authlevel provided in the func new command.
You should change the anonymous to ANONYMOUS in the command.
Change the command as below:
func new --name HttpExample --template "HTTP trigger" --authlevel "ANONYMOUS"

Or you can just change below line in the function code
auth_level=func.AuthLevel.anonymous

to
auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS

function_app.py:
import azure.functions as func
import datetime
import json
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.route(route="HttpExample", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def HttpExample(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )

Output:
C:\Users\uname\pyfunc> func start
Found Python version 3.11.9 (py).

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.6280 Commit hash: N/A +421f0144b42047aa289ce691dc6db4fc8b6143e6 (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.834.3.22875

[2024-12-20T14:18:44.871Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        HttpExample:  http://localhost:7071/api/HttpExample

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-12-20T14:18:49.220Z] Executing 'Functions.HttpExample' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=3fb0fddd-4f96-4d7c-bd8f-b0fdee4aa3a1)
[2024-12-20T14:18:49.408Z] Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-12-20T14:18:49.574Z] Executed 'Functions.HttpExample' (Succeeded, Id=3fb0fddd-4f96-4d7c-bd8f-b0fdee4aa3a1, Duration=444ms)
[2024-12-20T14:18:50.070Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.



Thank you for your response. Implementing the suggested changes unfortunately did not mitigate the issue. The CLI commands were directly taken from the Azure documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-python?tabs=windows%2Cbash%2Cazure-cli%2Cbrowser

Did you change anonymous to ANONYMOUS?

The func tools help lists the allowed values as [function, anonymous, admin]..

Yes, I change the spelling to uppercase...

Can you run the function now?

No, the error remains the same unfortunately..

Can you create a new function again in a new folder? func init and func new. you can select the trigger and authlevel from the displayed options.

I used the updated command from your response in a new folder. The error still occurs...

Did you create virtual environment?

Try creating the function with 3.11 Python version.

Downgrading the Python version from 3.12  to 3.11 solved the issue. Thank you!

Make sure to change to from anonymous to ANONYMOUS manually. Changing only the flag still resulted in an incorrect https trigger example in my case.
